# Copying formula for dynamic range

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I have a Macro to place a division formula in a cell in row "d", and replicates the same formula all the way in row "d" till the last cell.
I am trying to replicate the same formula across other columns "E:L" without having to rewrite the entire code for each column seperately

```
With wbk4.Sheets("USD")
Set clDest = .Range("D2")
Set clLookup = .Range("AA2")
End With

If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
End If
clDest.Formula = "=(" & clLookup.Address(False, False) & " / 3.68)"
```

This does the correct formula for the mentioned column "D" till the last cell.
What i need is this to be replicated across the following columns "E" to "L"
only from the 2nd cell till the last row.

I tried to do it through the below logic, but its a bit too complicated and does not work, Im sure there is another way around :)

```
With wbk4.Sheets("USD")
lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("D2" & lrow).Copy
wbk4.Sheets("USD").Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty solution simply replace

```
Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
```

with

```
Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, x)
```

where x is the number of columns you want to fill.